# export results of MarkLogic query (mlcp, xdmp.save)

Tags: export, marklogic, mlcp

I have a simple query that filter documents based on the value of a property and return their results.

eg :

```
var query = 'Yes'
const jsearch = require('/MarkLogic/jsearch');
const myPaths = { paths: ['/envelope/instance/entity'] };
result = jsearch.documents()
    .where(jsearch.byExample({ property: query }))
    .map({ extract: myPaths })
    .result();
```

Is it possible to use MLCP or a MarkLogic API to save the results of this query as JSON? Compressed results?

Based on this documentation https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/export#id_47556 it is possible to do so. But I don't know how to serialize a query that uses jsearch instead of cts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first extract `jsearch` query and serialise it as `-query_filter` option.

Then you combine `-query_filter`  and `-document_selector` option to export the specified node.

> The `mlcp` `options_file` translation of your `jsearch` query is:

```
export
-mode
local
-host
localhost
-port
***
-username
***
-password
***
-output_file_path 
***
-document_selector
{path-expression}
-query_filter
{"jsonPropertyValueQuery":{"property":["property"], "value":["Yes"]}}
```